# Need help getting this color effect look

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, blend-modes, channel

I've been trying to get a similar look as the photos in this image with the different color effects. I've tried messing with different blending options and even tried different gradient maps. However, I can't seem to get it quite right.

Does anyone know what I'll need to do to achieve this one color effect for each photo?

[image]

Comment: Blending modes is also an option. You might want to clarify why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a selection over the area which needs a new color. Apply Image > Adjustments > Hue & Saturation > Colorize:

[image]

As you see black and white get no color, the brightest color goes where the brightness was about 50% of the maximum. If you have an image which is well adjusted as a normal photo (=full scale from black to white is in use) and you want the white areas get the brightest color move the lightness slider to minus 50%:

[image]

You can use adjustment layers for bigger flexibility. A curves layer is good for contrast adjustments and a Black&White-layer is good for searching the best monochrome contrast if your image happens to be colored. Hue&Saturation layer is good for searching the right final color if you aim something else than just pure red, green and blue.

If you do not want to mess with adjustment layers and layer masks and you start from color photos use Image > Adjustments > Black&White to get at first a good contrast BW-image. Use reduced lightness in the colorization. Without searching at first a good contrast BW mix the result can be too flat.